# Is there assembler REPL under linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, debugging, read-eval-print-loop

Recently I've started plaing with assembler under linux, there's good debuger, but comming from Ruby I'm missing simple REPL that would let me enter a line of assembler code and see the result on registers flags and stack.

Can anyone point me in good direction?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448580/interpreting-assembly-code

Answer (score 8):

Linux isn't supported yet, but if someone needs an assembly REPL for OS X, I have created one: https://github.com/Tyilo/asm_repl

**Update:** Rappel seems to be what you are looking for: https://github.com/yrp604/rappel

Comment: Linux support would be awesome <3

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like [bastard](http://bastard.sourceforge.net/)? Never used it, but it looks like it has some sort of interactive mode.